# Python: using setdiff to assign to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
>>> n1 = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 9])
```

From this, I can get the number of elements from the beginning up to the highest value before the next lower number begins begins like this:

```
>>> wherediff = np.where(n1[1:]-n1[:-1] < 0)
>>> wherediff = wherediff[0] + 1
>>> wherediff
array([3, 6, 8])
```

I can insert a 0 at the beginning of this array:

```
>>> wherediff = np.insert(wherediff, 0, 0)
>>> wherediff
array([0, 3, 6, 8])
```

And I can get the number of elements between each successive value:

```
>>> sum_vals = np.abs(wherediff[1:] - wherediff[:-1])
>>> sum_vals
array([3, 3, 2])
```

Now, I want to generate another numpy array with the following properties:

- for elemennts 0 through 2 inclusive, I want the value 1 (the number of 1s is `sum_vals[0]`, and I want it in positions `range(wherediff[0], wherediff[1])`
- for elements 3 through 5 inclusive, I want the value 2 (the number of 2s is `sumvals[1]`, and I want it in positions `range(wherediff[1], wherediff[2])`
- for elements 6 through 7 inclusive, I want the value 3
- for the last elements, I want the value 4

I tried this:

```
>>> n3 = []
>>> for i in range(1, wherediff.shape[0]):
...     s1 = set(range(wherediff[i]))
...     s2 = set(range(wherediff[i-1]))
...     s3 = np.setdiff1d(s1, s2)[0]
...     n3.append(np.repeat(i, len(s3)))
```

thinking I'd switch to an array later, but the `setdiff1d` function is not performing as expected. It's doing this:

```
>>> for i in range(1, wherediff.shape[0]):
...     s1 = set(range(wherediff[i]))
...     s2 = set(range(wherediff[i-1]))
...     s3 = np.setdiff1d(s1, s2)[0]
...     print(s3)
...
set([0, 1, 2])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

whereas I would want;

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8, 9, 10
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip all the setdiff1d stuff and the index manipulation and work with an array of booleans:

```
flags = n1[1:] < n1[:-1]
flags = np.insert(flags, 0, True)

result = np.cumsum(flags)
```

The `cumsum` adds 1 to the sum for every `True`, so once for the first element and once for every time an element of `n1` was less than the previous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using native python sets you may as well do the diff operation without numpy:

```
wherediff = np.array([0, 3, 6, 8])

for i in range(1, wherediff.shape[0]):
    s1 = set(range(wherediff[i]))
    s2 = set(range(wherediff[i-1]))
    s3 = np.array(list(s1 - s2))
    print(s3)
```

If you want to do everything in numpy then this is the way:

```
for i in range(1, wherediff.shape[0]):
    s1 = np.array(range(wherediff[i]))
    s2 = np.array(range(wherediff[i-1]))
    s3 = s3 = np.setdiff1d(s1, s2)
    print(s3)
```

Note that you can use `assume_unique=True` here...